# Crash when a tap recogniser calls its action method

Tags: ios, uitableview, uigesturerecognizer, uitapgesturerecognizer

In my app, I added in `viewWillAppear:` a gesture recogniser to a `tableView`:

```
self.tapGestureRecognizer = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapGestureTap:)];
self.tapGestureRecognizer.delegate = self;
self.postView.commentsTableView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
[self.postView.commentsTableView addGestureRecognizer:self.tapGestureRecognizer];
```

In most cases, tapping the table view works fine, and calls

```
- (void)tapGestureTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {
    if (gestureRecognizer.state == UIGestureRecognizerStateEnded) {
    …
}
```

However, in very rare cases, the app crashes. Crash log:
[image]It seems to me that the crash happens before the if statement in `tapGestureTap:` is executed.
But I have no idea which array is being accessed, nor why an object at index 0 should be accessed that does not exist.
Any idea what could be wrong or how to catch the error is highly welcome!

**EDIT** (due to the request below):

`cellForRow` method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    CommentCellTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:POST_COMMENTS_TABLEVIEWCELL forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Comment  *comment = self.commentsViewModel.comments[indexPath.row];
    NSString *text = comment.comment;
    User *belongsToUser = comment.belongsToUser;

    // Make age string
    NSDate *updatedAt = comment.updatedAt;
    NSAttributedString *age = [NSDate makeAgeString:updatedAt color:[UIColor grayColor]];

    [cell setUserName:belongsToUser.username comment:text age:age];

    NSURL *thumbnailURL = [NSURL URLWithString:belongsToUser.thumbnail];
    [cell.userImageView setImageWithURL:thumbnailURL];

    return cell;
}
```

Comment: Can you please post your cellForRow method? This error often occurs when tableView is loading, and numberOfRows return value is greater than actual number of cells generated from datasource. Also, may i ask why you add tap gesture to a tableView?

Comment: Which line is #654 in PostViewController.m?  Is the exception stack trace from the main thread?

Comment: @silentBob: Will post it in a minute.

Comment: @Phillip Mills: Line #654 is the lines with `- (void)tapGestureTap:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)gestureRecognizer {`

Comment: @silentBob Somebody used the tap gesture to identify the cell that was tapped. I admit, this seems also strange to me: I think I could also use simply `tableView:didSelectRowAtIndexPath:` instead, although I still had to check it.

Comment: People do tend to overengineer ;)

Comment: @PhillipMills: Yes, the stack trace is from the main thread.

Comment: Sorry, cellForRow alone does not cut it (silly me), but you might want to check your comments array count and numberOfRows. 
Also, from tapGestureTap method we can only see that it's checking recognizer state, does it also manipulate comments array in any way?

Comment: You can identify the crash by going to `Breakpoint navigator`. Then click on the plus (+) button at the bottom and add  `Exception Breakpoint`. Now re-run the application and the breakpoint will show you which array is causing the issue.

Comment: @silentBob: The table displays without problems. The app crashes (very rarely) when the table is tapped and the gesture recogniser calls its action method. The action method, however, is not entered - the crash happens before it enters it.

Comment: @The Mach System: Unfortunately, it did never happen during testing. The crash is reported via CrashLytics by an external beta tester.